# Virtuoso SPARQL Bug with BIND

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, virtuoso

I think I found a bug with the `BIND` function of SPARQL in Virtuoso.  I am running this in http://dbpedia.org/snorql/

Consider the following code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?companyShort
WHERE{
        ?org rdf:type dbo:Company ;
            rdfs:label ?label .        
        #BIND (UCASE(SUBSTR(?label,1,3)) as ?companyShort)
        filter langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" )
        filter(?label="About.com"@en)
}
```

This behaves as expected.  Now remove the comment on the `BIND` and *poof* the results vanish.  Why would the results vanish if I bind some string manipulation to another variable?

Comment: Your report is not about *SPARQL*, but about *Virtuoso*, the SPARQL processor behind DBpedia. This needs some further analysis. I encourage you to raise an [issue to the Virtuoso project on GitHub](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/). (Note that your first `FILTER` is redundant, since your second `FILTER` includes the `@en` langtag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others may provide the reason for this behavior, but you can fix it by changing the label filter to `str(?label)="About.com"`, so the query would look as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?companyShort
WHERE{
        ?org rdf:type dbo:Company ;
            rdfs:label ?label .        
        BIND (UCASE(SUBSTR(?label,1,3)) as ?companyShort)
        filter langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" )
        filter(str(?label)="About.com")
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, it actually seems like a bug in Virtuoso. Just tested on GraphDB and the original query works there without any problems.